# How to make a pattern rule in a Makefile with multiple patterns?

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, gnu-make

I want to make a GNU Makefile, in which for every targets like

```
<dirname>/stamp-<stampname>:
```

the following command is executed:

```
cd <dirname> && make stamp-<stampname>
```

As I've read here, the so-named [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples) can do some quite similar, i.e. for example to call a C compiler to produce the `.o`-s from any sources (`.c`):

```
%.o: %.c
  $(CC) -o ...
```

They could solve my problem, but as you can see, in my case, multiple `%` directives would be needed. Ideally, if a syntax element like

```
%1/stamp-%2:
  cd %1 && make stamp-%2
```

would exist, it would solve everything. But it doesn't. Does some workaround exist for the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
STAMPS:=$(shell ls **/stamp-*)

all: $(STAMPS)

.PHONY: $(STAMPS)
$(STAMPS):
    cd $(dir $@) && $(MAKE) $(notdir $@)
```

This assumes the `stamp-` files are always present and can be collected with `ls`. If they are not, you will have to specify them manually, e.g. `STAMPS:=foo/stamp-1 bar/stamp-2 ...`.

Comment: Using [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) would be better than `ls` (unless you really need the `**` glob).